# How to pass data from a DataGridView to another VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Lets say I have a Form with 2 sections, Party Section(where goes party images)and School section (where goes school images). Each section can store n images (All images are in my Image_Table in SQL Server).

So here is my problem. I have a DataGridView in every section to shows the images and Two fill methods:

```
Me.Image_TableTableAdapter.FillByPartyImages(Me.CAR_AuxDataSet.Image_Table, partyId)
```

and a:

```
Me.Image_TableTableAdapter.FillBySchoolImages(Me.CAR_AuxDataSet.Image_Table, schoolId)
```

The two dgv are associated with the same Table Adapter so, when one fill method executes, fills the two dgvs.

I tried to execute first fill method(fill the dgvPartyImages  and the dgvSchoolImages with party images), save the data from the dgvPartyImages to an dgvAux,  execute second method (fill the dgvPartyImages  and the dgvSchoolImages with school images) and then  retrieve data from de dgvAux to the dgvPartyImages, but I can't make it work

Here is the code:

```
Dim dgvAuxReq As New DataGridView

Me.Image_TableTableAdapter.FillByPartyImages(Me.CAR_AuxDataSet.Image_Table, partyId)
dgvAux.DataSource = dgvPartyImages.DataSource
Me.Image_TableTableAdapter.FillBySchoolImages(Me.CAR_AuxDataSet.Image_Table, schoolId)
dgvPartyImages.DataSource = dgvAux.DataSource
'This code does not work
```

The solution so far is fill the two dgv with

```
Me.Image_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CAR_AuxDataSet.Image_Table)
```

and then filter by partyId and schoolId:

```
Dim bsPary As New BindingSource
Dim bsSchool As New BindingSource

bsParty.DataSource = dgvPartyImages.DataSource
bsParty.Filter = "Id_Party = " & partyId.ToString
dgvPartyImages.DataSource = bsParty
bsSchool.DataSource = dgvSchoolImages.DataSource
bsSchool.Filter = "Id_School = " & schoolId.ToString
dgvSchoolImages.DataSource = bsSchool
```

That work, but make my app slow. So, how pass data from one DataGridView to another.

Any help will be appreciated, I've been searching without any results.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @SeanLange How can I pass data from one DataGridView to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to download all of the data once and then use a LINQ query to separate the data.  Here is a reference for learning LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx.  They provide examples and such.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don´t get it how this could solve my problem. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken as to what you're trying to do.  You will want your Party Images and your School images to both be implemented by an interface like IImages with following properties: The Image, the Id, and a third enum for a party or a school image.  You would then have all of the data downloaded to a List(Of IImages) in which you could just call AllImages. Then do: 

dgvPartyImages.DataSource = AllImages.Where(Function(img) img.Id = PartyId.ToString() And img.Type=Party)

dgvSchoolImages.DataSource = AllImages.Where(Function(img) img.Id = SchoolId.ToString() And img.Type=School)

Comment: Thanks again, but i wanted something simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

I just got rid of the fill methods, and called the images by sql commands. Both dataGridView gets filled with its respective images. Now when I call the images is faster than earlier.

```
Private Sub fillPartyImages()
    Dim img As New DataGridViewImageCell
    Dim row() As Object
    Dim connection As New Connection
    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connection.readConection)
    Dim PictureCol As Integer = 0 
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT Image FROM Image_Table WHERE Id_Party = @Id_Party", sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Party", partyId)
    Using sqlConnection
        sqlConnection.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Do While dr.HasRows
            Do While dr.Read()
                Dim b(dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
                dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, b, 0, b.Length)
                Dim ImgStream As New IO.MemoryStream(b)
                img.Value = Image.FromStream(ImgStream)
                row = {img.Value}
                dgvPartyImages.Rows.Add(row)
                ImgStream.Dispose()
            Loop
            dr.NextResult()
        Loop
        dr.Close()
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```